# trouble connecting to WIFI Network with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking

Good morning,

I work for a school board in Montreal and we are introducing Ubuntu and it's derivatives as a solution to give our older technology new life.

We have mostly used ubuntu and Edubuntu 12.04.4 LTS and it works great. When we try to use a more recent version such as 14.04 we are not able to connect to our wireless network. For security we use WPA2 enterprise, PEAP authentication, PEAP version automatic, inner authentication, MSCHAPv2,.

I don't understand why we would get a connection using the exact same configuration with version 12.04.4 and it does not work with 14.04. We have noticed the same thing when trying Lubuntu 14.04 and Xubuntu 14.04.

Any help would be greatly appreciated